# How do I connect through ssh to a server which doens't have a public IP (is behind a NAT)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, nat

Suppose I have a computer at home with a local address in a NAT like 192.168.100.42 which is my ssh server and I want to access it through other computer outside of this local network. Which IP and port I type in to login in `ssh hostname@IPaddress -p XXXX` and how do I get those since the NAT changes both outside of the local network?

Comment: You need a VPN to your home computer or a team (other party) approach like ShowMYPC or Team Viewer.

Comment: It can be achieved by VPN-setting a VPN connection between the outside network and your ssh server

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your router to pass a specific port number to the ssh port on 192.168.100.42.   Take an unusual port number, eg. one not found in /etc/services, like 8765, so that you don't get hammered by bots trying to get access.  Then:

```
ssh -p 8765 username@PublicIPA
```

will allow you to log on to 192.168.100.42.

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding, but you going to need security or you going to get hacked.

Maybe using a certificate inside of credentials for login.

You should find something like fail2ban or equivalent for your OS to keep the bad guys at bay.

This is one of the most common attacked ports, even if you move it to another port it will eventually be discovered.